# Объявление шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть класс:

```
template <class T>
class cFunction {
public:
    cFunction(T* _func, int _n);
    float getY(int num);
private:
    T* func;
};
```

и есть класс:

```
class cFunction1 {
public:
    cFunction1(float _a, float _b, float _x);
    cFunction1();
    void setParams(float _a, float _b, float _x);
    float getY();
private:
    float a, b, x;
};
```

который может передаваться в качестве параметра для класса cFunction.

Как объявить объект класса cFunction с параметром cFunction1?

Такая конструкция:

```
cFunction <cFunction1> *func = new cFunction<cFunction1>(f1, size);
```

выдает ошибки:

```
undefined reference to `cFunction<cFunction1>::cFunction(cFunction1*, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: А реализация метода cFunction(T* _func, int _n) была написана?
Тут скорее всего компоновщик не нашел ее.

Comment: Была:

    template <class T>
    cFunction <T>::cFunction(T *_func, int _n)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < _n; i++) {
            func[i] = _func[i];
        }
    }

Comment: я так понял я неправильно реализовал метод в cpp-шнике, ибо сделав инлайн вставку в прототипе класса все работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хм.

Шаблоны в C++, в отличие от, например, .NET, -- конструкция времени компиляции. То есть, во время выполнения программы шаблонов не существует, существуют только конкретные специализации.

А теперь подумайте: если реализация вашего шаблонного класса в `.cpp`, откуда компилятор узнает, что нужно скомпилировать специализацию для шаблонного параметра `cFunction1`? Никак: когда он компилирует `.cpp`-файл с шаблоном, он не знает, какие специализации нужны, а когда он компилирует место, где заказывается специализация, у него нету исходников шаблона.

Решение -- вынесите весь шаблонный класс в `.h`. Обратите внимание, что весь, к примеру, STL написан по этому принципу: реализация находится в header'е.

Comment: Опять же читайте - http://www.comeaucomputing.com/4.0/docs/userman/export.html и про [gcc здесь][1]

[1]:http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/

Comment: @gecube: читайте и вы: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416872/using-export-keyword-with-templates

Comment: @gecube: и вот ещё: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl-export-keyword.html: "C++11 standardization committee has voted to remove the export feature from the language"

Comment: Я в соседней ветке эту ссылку давал вообще-то =) Ну, что поделать - export как бы есть и его как бы нет. Возможно добавят в следующих версиях стандарта. Аргументацией против `export` была существенно возросшая сложность компилятора. Интересно, кто-нибудь здесь из пользователей считает export templates удобной и(или) нужной фичей?

Comment: @gecube: которую из них? export'а нет, и уже не будет (кроме Comeau), его отменили в C++11. export был бы отличной фичей, но по факту надеяться на него нельзя. Если минус ваш, хотелось бы узнать, за что.

Answer (score 1):

Компиляторы очень не любят, когда объявление шаблона идет в хедере, а реализация - в cpp-файле. Вот тогда и возникает ошибка линковки. 
Нужно реализацию в хедере оставлять.

Comment: @Abyx чтобы утверждать про `все` компиляторы - надо их всех и проверить, а это в принципе невозможно.

Comment: @Abyx в Стандарте где-то сказано, что надо реализацию шаблона в хедере оставлять? У меня совершенно спокойно может быть приватная шаблонная функция с реализацией в `cpp`-файле и всё будет работать.

Comment: @Abyx только в ответе вот формулировка иная. И в общем случае, она не соответствует истине.